# pyodbc connection to Teradata not working after upgrade to Teradata 16.00 driver

Tags: python, teradata, pyodbc

I have a Windows application that utilizes pyodbc to connect to Teradata. Currently, the clients have either the 14.10 or 15.00 drivers installed to perform this connection. The connection is made using this (simplified) code:

```
import pyodbc
constr = 'DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME='+dbname+';UID='+uid+';PWD='+pwd+';QUIETMODE=YES;'
pyodbc.pooling = False
pyodbc.connect(constr, ANSI=True, autocommit=True)
```

After upgrading to the 16.00 driver, this no longer works. Instead it throws the following error on the same code:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0)    (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I've tried a few variations of the connection string but all return the same error:

```
constr = """DRIVER={Teradata};DSN='+dbname+';UID='+uid+';PWD='+pwd+';QUIETMODE=YES;"""
constr = """DRIVER={Teradata};DSN='+dbname+';DATABASE='+dbname+';UID='+uid+';'+pwd+';QUIETMODE=YES;"""
constr = """Provider=Teradata;DBCNAME='+dbname+';DATABASE='+dbname+';UID='+uid+';PWD='+pwd+';QUIETMODE=YES;"""
```

What do I need to do to utilize 16.00 teradata drivers and pyodbc?

Comment: That error sounds like the ODBC driver isn't installed correctly. Check your ODBC Administrator (32 bit or 64 bit to match whatever version ODBC Driver you installed) and confirm that your Teradata driver is installed in the `Driver` tab and is of the expected version.

Comment: @JNevill That was my initial thought too, but it does appear correctly in the ODBC administrator panel: https://i.imgur.com/uyrqxHH.png

Comment: Is it the right architecture for the pyodbc library you are using? Like if pyodbc is 64 bit, is the 64 bit driver installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. This recommendation may sound silly, but my server admins changed the name of the connection string and Windows SQLDriverConnect was bombing.

On my workstation, in the DSN connection list, the DSN name is "TDPROD" and the string description is "Teradata".  However, on the server, the DSN name is "TDPROD" and the string description is "Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.10".  So, I had to update my python function from this (Please note that I'm using Python 3.6 so I can use "f" strings; if you're using an earlier version of Python make sure you perform string interpolation by using supported methodologies):

```
    pyodbc.connect(f"""DRIVER=Teradata;
                       DBCNAME=TDPROD;
                       UID={user};
                       PWD={password};
                       QUIETMODE=YES""",
                       autocommit=True,
                       unicode_results=True)
```

to this:

```
    pyodbc.connect(f"""DRIVER=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.10;
                       DBCNAME=TDPROD;
                       UID={user};
                       PWD={password};
                       QUIETMODE=YES""",
                       autocommit=True,
                       unicode_results=True)
```

Hope this helps to at least give you something else to check that wasn't immediately obvious to me.